# C# Global Component Code

Tags: c#, .net

i'm new to C# i've been messing around to discover this language so far i've wrote many programs in my quest but now i'm stuck with one thing, i can't explain by words but codes can say what i want so here we go i know it's silly program but it's for education purpose only :D

```
Private void change()
        {
anycontrol.BackColor = Color.Gold; // when this function called the control's BackColor will Change to gold
        }
// example
private void TextBox1_Focused(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Change(); // this suppose to change the color of the controls which is now textbox1 i want it to work on other controls such as buttons progressbars etc
}
```

now after i explained my problem i may ask you if you can to help it will be appreciated.

Comment: not the best explain ... what is your problem? are you sure you are calling right method? `Change` != `change`. C# is case sensitive

Comment: i've edited the question and yes i called the right function.

Comment: put your real code, because this will not work, seriously, then try to debug, see if any exception see if any exception is thrown etc.

Comment: i want a command instead of the "anycontroll" that will work on all controls instead of typing there names for example if i want to change  textbox's back color i will type textbox1.BackColor = color.gold; if i can replace the control name with a command that will work on the other controls i tried this.BackColor = color.gold; it will change the forms backcolor only

Comment: Though i am not sure how much new you are to programming, but focusing on some of the programming language constructs such as passing parameter(s) to methods and utilizing the inheritance hierarchy will certainly help you do what you want for this specific problem. Also you didn't mentioned whether you are using WPF/Web Forms/Win Forms since you are asking about commands in your comment.

Comment: thanx for your suggestion i will try what you mentioned above after i'm done with this obstacle , btw i'm using winforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method that takes a [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) and a [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) as a parameter, and anything that inherits from `Control` (i.e. `TextBox`, `DropDownList`, `Label` etc.) will work with this:

```
void SetControlBackgroundColour(Control control, Color colour)
{
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.BackColor = colour;
    }
}
```

In your example, you could use it like this:

```
private void TextBox1_Focused(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetControlBackgroundColour(sender as Control, Color.Gold);
}
```

In response to the comments, you could then use this method in a recursive method that will set the background colour for each control on the form:

```
void SetControlBackgroundColourRecursive(Control parentControl, Color colour)
{
    if (parentControl != null)
    {
        foreach (Control childControl in parentControl.Controls)
        {
            SetControlBackgroundColour(childControl, colour);

            SetControlBackgroundColourRecursive(childControl);
        }
    }
}
```

And then call this function on your `Form` object (`this`) in your `Form1_Load` method (assuming the form is called `Form1`):

```
protected void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetControlBackgroundColourRecursive(this, Color.Gold);
}
```

Comment: your code semi-helped me i still have to type the name of the control, is there any method that can get the control name and pass it to ChangeBackgroundColour(Here, Color.Gold); instead of typing the control name ?

Comment: I've just put the code you require to make use of the `sender` parameter. Note that `as` can yield `null`, so have added protection for that case in `ChangeBGColour`

Comment: @weston Sorry, I did reload the edits but I must have missed something, I don't think I used `as` anywhere did I? =]

Comment: No I did, it got lost in edits. But nevermind I have restored it now. Look at `sender as Control`, saves OP typing `TextBox1` and the event method can be reused then.

Comment: you code really helped me if you don't mind i've edited it to look like this :System.Drawing.Color colour = new System.Drawing.Color();

void ChangeBackgroundColour(Control control, Color colour)
        {
            if (control != null)
            {
                control.BackColor = colour = Color.Gold; ;
               
            }
        }
private void TextBox1_Focused(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ChangeBackgroundColour(sender as Control, colour);
}

Comment: @VoVb Of course I don't mind, all that matters is that you got a working solution and hopefully learned something along the way =]

Comment: can you suggest something to learn so i can get along with these problems ?

Comment: @VoVb Patience and practise? I can't think of anything specific, just keep writing code and solving real problems, it's the best way to learn =]